# Interceptors vs Aspects in Spring?

Tags: spring, interceptor, aspects

I am trying to use interceptors in Spring. I want to implement an interceptor on some methods to handle specific logic when these methods are called. I also want to be apart from using web framework, as am tending to use Spring as back end, without any headers.

After searching, I think spring approach is called Aspects, could you please mention best practice to do this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In Spring there are two different constructs that get called "interceptors".

First, there are [Handler Interceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor), which are part of the Spring MVC framework, and allow you to add interceptor logic to web requests. I suspect this is what you meant when you said "interceptors"

Then you have Method Interceptors, which are part of the [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop.html) framework. These are much more general mechanism than Handler Interceptors, but also potentially more complex. In AOP terminology, such interceptors provide a means of coding the "aspects" you're talking about. The

AOP aspects are a complex subject. If you're interested, I suggest that you skim over the stuff in the [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop.html) and get a feel for the terminology, and what it can and can't do for you.

Comment: you are totally getting the point, i understand now that interceptors as term will be related to web requests, and that isn't what i need, i need the method interceptors indeed, and after reading through documents, i think it's complex some way, so is there a simpler way to perform it

Comment: Excellent answer.  it is very useful while develop this concepts in the project