# Writing custom annotations in java - TimeCounter annotation example

Tags: java, java-8, annotations, java-annotations

Basically I have a requirement to track time spent in a method using custom annotation. (I know spring AOP can be used for this, but we can not use it in our product).

```
public class TimeCounterDemo {
    
    @TimeCounter
    public void trackMyTimeSpentUsingAnnotation()
    {
        //some heavy processing stuff
    }   
}

public @interface TimeCounter {
  //need help with this implementation.
}
```

So, my requirement is to complete the `TimeCounter` annotation.
The requirement are simple -

1. Log time of method start.
2. Log time of method end.
3. Log total time spent in method.
4. Name of method executed

Could someone help on how to implement this annotation to above requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already many libraries that have such annotations available.
If you want your own implementation, one of the appraoches would be to use [dynamic proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html):

Here's how your `TimeCounterDemo` may look like:

**TimeCounter (Annotation)**

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface TimeCounter {

}
```

**ITimerCounterDemo (Interface)**

```java
public interface ITimerCounterDemo {
    @TimeCounter
    public void trackMyTimeSpentUsingAnnotation();

    public void someOtherMethod(int a);
}
```

**TimerCounterDemo (Implementation of above interface)**

```java
public class TimerCounterDemo implements ITimerCounterDemo {
    
    public void trackMyTimeSpentUsingAnnotation() {
        System.out.println("TimerCounterDemo:: Going to sleep");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("TimerCounterDemo:: Completed.");
    }

    public void someOtherMethod(int a) {
        System.out.println("In someothermethod with value:: " + a);
    }
}
```

**TimerProxy**

```java
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;

public class TimerProxy implements InvocationHandler {

    private Object targetObj;

    public static Object newInstance(Object targetObj) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(targetObj);
        return Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                      targetObj.getClass().getClassLoader(), 
                      targetObj.getClass().getInterfaces(),
                      new TimerProxy(targetObj)
               );
    }

    private TimerProxy(Object targetObj) {
        this.targetObj = targetObj;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(TimeCounter.class)) {

            LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
            Object returnObj = method.invoke(targetObj, args);

            System.out.println(method.getName() + " executed in "
                    + Duration.between(start, LocalDateTime.now()).getSeconds() + " seconds");
            return returnObj;
        }

        return method.invoke(targetObj, args);
    }

}
```

Testing the timer:

```java
public class TimerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ITimerCounterDemo t = (ITimerCounterDemo) TimerProxy.newInstance(new TimerCounterDemo());
        t.someOtherMethod(10);
        t.trackMyTimeSpentUsingAnnotation();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```java
In someothermethod with value:: 10
TimerCounterDemo:: Going to sleep
TimerCounterDemo:: Completed.
trackMyTimeSpentUsingAnnotation executed in 2 seconds
```

You can read more about it [here](https://dzone.com/articles/java-dynamic-proxy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750665/how-to-get-method-annotations-on-a-proxied-class)

Comment: wonderful implementation +1.  So, your implementation uses dynamic proxies which you linked. Right? And are annotations on interface methods inherited by implementing classes. This post says otherway - [Why java classes do not inherit annotations from implemented interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces)

Comment: @joven, Correct, we are using proxies. We didn't put `@TimerCounter` at interface for subclasses to inherit; it's so we can check for the annotation at `invoke` method. Proxy works with interfaces (hence the name dynamic proxies.) I put it on interface for simplicity. You can put the annotation at methods declared inside class too.  You have `targetObj` and can check for annotations at its methods (like: `targetObj.getClass().getMethods()`) and act accordingly.

Comment: @joven Note that we still (when we put `@TimeCounter` on method def inside `TimerCounterDemo`) need `ITimerCounterDemo`. This is because proxies work with interfaces. We cannot have `TimerCounterDemo t = (TimerCounterDemo) TimerProxy.newInstance(new TimerCounterDemo());`. The casting and assignment type has to be one of the interfaces implemented by `TimerCounterDemo`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing an annotation, you implement time tracking directly in your method.
The first 2 lines in your method must be

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
logger.info("Method started at = " + new Date(startTime);
```

Now you have to log the total time taken by the method. This can be done by writing the below statement into the same method

```
logger.info("Total time taken by the method is = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
```

Comment: i know this.. could you delete your answer. I am thinking of deleting this Q